# Converting a String to a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am trying to convert the following string value into a javascript object
Example

```
string="name=usernamex&gender=boy&age=10&version_obj=1"
```

into

```
var user={ name:'username', gender:'boy',age:10,version_obj=1}
```

Can someone help me out

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want the `querystring` module: http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

```
querystring.parse('foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge') 
// { foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without node? 
Edit: Nevermind, this was answered below

Comment: @JeremyW - sure, there are plenty of ways, see plbsam's answer below for a raw JS version. But if you're using node already, as the OP's tags indicated, this is the easy way.

Answer (score 1):

with pure javascript..

```
var str="name=usernamex&gender=boy&age=10&version_obj=1";
var array = str.split('&');
var obj = {};
array.forEach(function(value){
    var x = value.split('=');
    obj[x[0]] = decodeURIComponent(x[1]);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Your script does not properly handle URI-encoded values

Comment: can you give an example? @JonathanGray

Comment: FYI the key also needs to be decoded. Check my example again ;)

Comment: We only use ASCII chars as keys. Is it really necessary?

Comment: Only if you care about handling all use-case scenarios. Actually here's another biggie we both forgot about... Cases of malformed input. A simple query such as "one" or "one=two" would throw an exception if I'm not mistaken!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a module:

```
var strArr = string.split("&");
var user = {}, i = 0, n;
while(i<strArr.length) {
    n = strArr[i].split("=");
    if(n.length == 2)
     user[decodeURIComponent(n[0])]
      = decodeURIComponent(n[1]);
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: * Example only, not for use in production environments.